# how to display 6 images in a loop on a imagview

Tags: swift, loops, imageview, uiimage, func

My swift code below right now displays 3 images in a loop in func alterImage. What I want to do is have 6 images displayed in a loop just like what I have below. The problem is I don't know how to add those three images to the sequence I have below. I added extra lines to what was in the func to try to figure out how to add image4,image5, and image6. Right now it has 4 lines.

```
      var backColor = UIImageView()
   let image1 = UIImage(named: "a.png")
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "b.png")
    let image3 = UIImage(named: "c.png")
    let image4 = UIImage(named: "d.png")
    let image5 = UIImage(named: "e.png")
    let image6 = UIImage(named: "f.png")

    @objc func alterImage() {

            backColor.image =
            backColor.image ==
            image1 ? image2 : backColor.image
            ==
            image2 ? image3 :  image1



        perform(#selector(alterImage), with: self, afterDelay: 1)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it seems that you are aiming to view the images in `backColor` image view sequentially every second. I'd suggest avoiding the currently used approach, you could group the images in an array instead. Example:

```
var backColor = UIImageView()
let image1 = UIImage(named: "a.png")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "b.png")
let image3 = UIImage(named: "c.png")
let image4 = UIImage(named: "d.png")
let image5 = UIImage(named: "e.png")
let image6 = UIImage(named: "f.png")
let images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
var currentImageIndex = 0

@objc func alterImage() {
    backColor.image = images[currentImageIndex]
    currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex == images.count - 1 ? 0 : currentImageIndex + 1
    perform(#selector(alterImage), with: self, afterDelay: 1)
}
```

At this point, when viewing the last image, it will get back to the first one.

Note: if you are doing it inside a `UIViewController`, you might need to declare the `images` as a lazy variable:

```
lazy var images: [UIImage?] = { [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6] }()
```

---

Furthermore, for the purpose of showing how it could be done by the current approach (and again, I'd recommend to avoid it), it could be done as:

```
// set the first image by default:
backColor.image = image1
@objc func alterImage() {
    backColor.image =
        backColor.image == image1 ? image2 :
        backColor.image == image2 ? image3 :
        backColor.image == image3 ? image4 :
        backColor.image == image4 ? image5 :
        backColor.image == image5 ? image6 : image1

    perform(#selector(alterImage), with: self, afterDelay: 1)
}
```

Comment: let images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6] is causing a compile error stating Cannot use instance member 'image1' within property initializer;

Comment: Where are you adding the images and the array?

Comment: just on the left panel

Comment: I can't figure it out, try to declare them in the right places...

Comment: added a photo above with the error. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: So you are declaring them in a `UIViewController` correct?

Comment: yes. However the uiimages are being added to the array is what is not working.

Comment: I just updated the answer, replace `images` array with the new one :)